# PlayStore app in some devices still showing older version while new version is live and available on play store

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

Some device's play store app is showing older version of my app(1.91) while new version(1.92) is available on play store. When I open the play store app programmatically to update my application from update button (which I have in my android app )of my app, play store app shows open button but it should have update button there(so user can update my app).

What should I do to resolve this problem. Should I unpublish the older version after publishing new version on play store

Comment: How long ago did you publish your app?

Comment: If you restart device, it should work! I have seen this before. Also notice that when using data bundles to connect to internet, updates are not automatic!

Comment: I publish my app on Saturday, but still on Monday this problem exists....

Comment: I cannot ask my user to restart device or clear chache. Is there any way to programmatically clears play store app cache data from my app.

Comment: @BHARATGUPTA did you ever find a solution to this? Im running into the same issue.

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Any solution?

Comment: Clear the play store app data.

Comment: There is no way for you to fix this on Users device. On your personal device you can restart/clear cache or data of Play store app and it should work. For your User to get the new version, they also need to clear Play Store app data & cache.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. This complicates my life a lot, because I need to tell the user to update, he clicks to go to PlayStore and the old version appears there.... Is there any way to force it?

By the way, has anyone tried InAppUpdates.... it seems like a solution.

Answer (score 31):

A little late to answer here, but this will help others who face this issue.

**Story:**

Time and again I have seen this happen with my apps where the new version is live and visible on some devices, but on others the Play store keeps on displaying older version.
This is some caching issue with Play store app.

**Solution:**

1. The solution is for the user to force stop the play store app and open it again.
2. If that doesn't work, clear play store app data/cache and open it again.
3. If that doesn't work, restart the device and open the app again.
4. If that doesn't work, ask your users to buy an iPhone and you can deploy an iOS app.

**Conclusion:**

Who should you blame for this issue? Google, of course.

Who will your user blame and give a bad rating to? You, of course.

P.S. Before arriving at this conclusion, make sure your app version is actually live on Play Store! You might also ask your user to send screen shot of play store listing version to confirm it.

Comment: yes, this happened to me, I solved it by clearing play store data.

Comment: last option though

Comment: clear cache playstore work for me

Comment: @RohmatulLaily Yes, but imagine your end users facing this issue. You can't just tell them it's an issue with the Play Store app & that they need to clear the data.

Comment: For me even after a month of app update, i can see few users are downloading older version from playstore shown in console. Really frustrating.

Comment: @Anukoolsrivastav Are you sure? Maybe you have a alpha/beta program where older version is being served. Maybe users are getting older version from another third part site and not play store. I can help you to perfectly control app versions if you need.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what i did, which resolved my issue,

1. Closed Playstore app from list of running apps.
2. Went to Settings -> Apps -> Google Play Store -> Force Stop.
3. Relaunch playstore and this time it showed me the update.

In one case although the app was no longer in review and was published, but had to wait for couple of hours before it showed up on that particular device. On another device (Samsung too) it updated immediately.