# Playstore showing the older version to some users While there is new version available

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-services

We have given two new updates in the last 15 days.
but still for some users its showing the older version of App.

We have increased the version code and version name with every update.
But for some devices still, it's showing the older version.

Here is the Scenario for the issue

**The latest app is updated on 19 June**

1.For the first time, the app store shows the Older version

**version Code: 207**

[image: enter link description here]

**2.After that when user visit to play store again
and search for the same App it shows
the next updated version.**

**version Code: 209**

[image]

**3. Again After that when user visit to play store
and search for the same App it shows
the latest updated version which is on 19th of june**

**version Code: 212**

[image]

We always upload the signed apk on Playstore.

Why it's not showing the latest update for the first time install.

Please help us with this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PlayStore app in some devices still showing older version while new version is live and available on play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955763/playstore-app-in-some-devices-still-showing-older-version-while-new-version-is-l)

Answer (score 0):

From Play Console support:

> Due to device connectivity and varying server load, it
> may take several days (in some cases a week) for app updates to reach
> all devices. The behavior you are seeing with the update being
> available on the web is common for apps. The mobile store will update
> in due course.

Comment: I have this behavior, but although the web play store already shows the correct update notes and description the version number of my app is still wrong. Will this change too?

Comment: Also, do you mind providing the link to the source?